# compare sender: Any? to UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, swift3

I am new to swift, and just happen to have Swift 3 released, but apple document still using Swift2 syntax.

Understand that below  (Swift2)

```
@IBOutlet var weak saveButton:UIBarButtonItem!
```

This method lets you configure a `ViewController` before it's presented.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?) {
if saveButton === sender {   //originally swift 2 can compare

}
```

Has changed to (Swift3)

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:Any){
}
```

Now on swift 3 I cannot check `if sender = saveButton`

I am very new to Swift, is that I need to cast it like `sender as UIBarButtonItem?`

[Original Apple Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH16-SW1)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like this inside `prepareforsegue` method.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:Any){
     if let barButton = sender as? UIBarButtonItem {
          if saveButton == barButton {
               //Do what you want
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if saveButton === barButton {` ?

Comment: @CamConnor Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to cast you just say `sender as! UIBarButtonItem` as easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also:

**1) Select a segue** you have created as a connection between a `UIBarButtonItem` and a target controller.

**2) Name it**:

[image]

**3) Test it**:

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "MyIdentifier" {
        // actions
    }
}
```